# openpyxl sheet.column_dimensions[].width slightly less than assignment

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to automate a process to set column widths on a spreadsheet. The code below is setting the width to 3.29, rather than 4.0. Am I missing a step?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from openpyxl import load_workbook

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
workbook = load_workbook(filename=path)
sheet = workbook.active
    
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 4.0

workbook.save(filename=path)
```

[Screenshot from spreadsheet of column with after processing by script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDAbC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of columns in Excel is an inexact science because it depends on the physical size of the screen and the resolution so you can approximate at best. For example, I have a script that sets the width to 14, which corresponds to 84 pixel on MacOS and 13.17 for Excel – it may well be calcuting the space available without padding, which you also, in theory, need to think about.

For further information you can read up on how width's are calculated in the OOXML specification. Then forget about it because screens and OSes have moved on since then.